# how to merge python in loop to get clist

Tags: python

Ask for an amount and whether it is taxable; calculate the sales tax and show the tax amount and the total including the tax; allow the user to do the sales tax calculation for multiple items.

Use 9.5% as the sales tax rate.

When the user finishes, tell what the grand total, tax and total, comes to.

Here is the data your demo.

## Amount          Taxable?

1          $10.00                  Y

2           11.00                   N

3            1.50                    N

4            2.99                    Y

5           12.00                   Y

here is what i did , I don't know how to get the total in for loop in clist

alist = []

amount = eval(input("How many amount do you want to calculate?"))

for i in range(amount):
    alist.append(input("amount" + str(i+1) + ":"))

```
print(alist)
```

blist = []

taxable = eval(input("How many amount taxable?"))

for n in range(taxable):
    blist.append(input("amount_taxable" + str(n+1) + ":"))

```
print(blist)
```

clist = list(zip(alist,blist))

print(clist)

for a,b in clist:

```
print(a,b)

if b =='Y':
    print("grand total" + ":", eval(a)*1.095)
    print("tax" + ":" , eval(a)*.095)
    print("total_of_taxable" + ":",len(clist)*eval(a)*1.095)

elif b == 'N':
    print("not taxable")
    print("total_of_not_taxable" + ":",eval(a)*len(clist))
```

Comment: It seems you're on Python 3, so you want `list(zip(alist, blist))`. Assuming those values are what you got from the input. That's not clear as you don't tell us what your current output is.

Comment: `list(zip(alist, blist))` or iterate over the `zip` object via a `for loop`

Answer (score 0):

I addition to Redi43's comment you should also

- convert the values that you are appending to your lists to ints
- not worry about starting the range at 0, as 0 is the default starting value

Something like this is a little better.

```
alist = []
blist = []

amount = int(input("How many amount do you want to calculate?"))
for i in range(amount):
    alist.append(int(input("amount" + str(i+1) + ":")))

taxable = int(input("How many amount taxable?"))
for n in range(taxable):
    blist.append(int(input("amount_taxable" + str(n+1) + ":")))


clist = list(zip(alist,blist))

print(clist)
```

Comment: Print statement in Python 3? :o Is this some kind of from __ past __ import sorcery?

Comment: Hi,thanks, I got clist now ,so in this question ,how can i get the last step

Comment: Ask for an amount and whether it is taxable; calculate the sales tax and show the tax amount and the total including the tax; allow the user to do the sales tax calculation for multiple items.

Use 9.5% as the sales tax rate.

When the user finishes, tell what the grand total, tax and total, comes to.

Here is the data your demo.

#          Amount          Taxable?

1          $10.00                  Y

2           11.00                   N

3            1.50                    N

4            2.99                    Y

5           12.00                   Y

Comment: @Reti43 nope, I was testing this in Python 2, no __past__ sorcery here.